# What is the use of Enable Separate Loading of Related Lists in user interface

Tags: user-interface

What will happen in our salesforce account if we enable or disable an option called **Enable Separate Loading of Related Lists** in **User Interface**.

I tried with many sites in google, but gives zero satisfaction.

please explain me about **Enable Separate Loading of Related Lists** with screen shots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you load a record detail page in Salesforce, you get the top half of the page that shows the fields and information for that record, and you also get the bottom half that shows related records to the page. The bottom half, the "Related Lists", could potentially take a while to load because Salesforce has to traverse their database to gather all the related objects.

If you "Enable Separate Loading of Related Lists", you can get the top half of the page to load first, then have the bottom half of the page load afterwards.

If you do not have the option enabled, you will have to wait for the entire page to load before you can view any information.

Comment: Let me check and inform you.

Comment: Like wise, i have few doubts in User interface. If you do not mind can you explain me, if you know about them?

Comment: what was that, i'll try to solve them.

Comment: I have confusion about **Enable Customization of Chatter User Profile Pages**

Comment: here is the link in that all the complete option is available regarding user interface 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_ui_settings.htm&type=0
Hope that will help you